# How gitlab server connect to gitlab runner to execute some commands

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Centos Instance and I have install and register a gitlab runner inside this instance. Now I wan to ask you: how gitlab server connect to gitlab runner client to execute some commands?, because in the registration process I haven´t provide any ssh or login credentials of the gitlab runner centos instance ...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't!

The gitlab-runner process polls the GitLab Server to check if there are any available jobs that this runner can process (for example by checking tags, runner version, etc). Each time it does this, the GitLab server updates the timestamp for this runner in the "last seen" field.

If there is at least one job this runner can run, it pulls down the details and removes the job from the queue, processes the job, updates the GitLab server with the results (success/failure) and uploads any artifacts.

All of this utilizes GitLab's HTTP API, so no keys or certificates are needed (other than the GitLab server's TLS certificate for HTTPS to work).

Hope this helps!